# Mocking an FileChooser in TestFx using mockito

Tags: java, javafx, mockito, junit5, testfx

I tried to test if a file is chosen in the inside an FileChooser and written as String into an TextField.

I am using:
testfx 4.0.4-alpha
mockito 2.1.0

I found this on the web:
https://gitter.im/TestFX/TestFX/archives/2017/10/05

Mocking the FileChooser:

```java
@Mock
FileChooser fileChooser = Mockito.mock(FileChooser.class);
```

My Test:

```java
@Test
public void testButtonBrowseClickWhenFileIsSelected () {
    clickOn("#btnBrowse");
    File inputFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("testfile.txt").getPath());
    when(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this.targetWindow())).thenReturn(inputFile);

    verifyThat("#txtFilePath", (TextField txtFilePath) -> !txtFilePath.getText().isEmpty()
            && (txtFilePath.getText().contains(".txt") || txtFilePath.getText().contains(".xml")));
}
```

When i run the test it fails.

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: applies on Predicate
     but: was <TextField[id=txtFilePath, styleClass=text-input text-field]>
Expected :applies on Predicate

Actual   :<TextField[id=txtFilePath, styleClass=text-input text-field]>
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.testfx.api.FxAssert.verifyThatImpl(FxAssert.java:150)
    at org.testfx.api.FxAssert.verifyThat(FxAssert.java:118)
    at com.frauscher.genplatformmd5calculator.GuiControllerTest.testButtonBrowseClickWhenFileIsSelected(GuiControllerTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an work around i am using sth like this.

I am basically copy pasting into the focused field of the FileChooser and than pressing Enter.

```java
private void applyPath(String filePath){
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(filePath);
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
    press(KeyCode.CONTROL).press(KeyCode.V).release(KeyCode.V).release(KeyCode.CONTROL);
    push(KeyCode.ENTER);
}
```

Comment: On Windows 10, with JavaFX 13, the pasting of the file name works great. However, the file is not opened. - The `ENTER` doesn't seem to have any effect. `org.testfx:testfx-core:4.0.17-alpha-SNAPSHOT`